# Delete and add columns in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the below code to create the validations in google sheet (contributed by Cooper), what this script does is it automatically check the applicable headers and create the dropdown with values and hide the columns which are not applicable.

I am trying to solve here is:

1. The script checks the applicable headers related to the Product Selection
2. It creates the dropdown with validation values
3. Instead of hiding the not applicable columns, It removes them from the sheet

I am a beginner to google script and tried using the deletecolumn function but unable to get it work.

Please help me out here.

```
function loadObjectsAndCreateProductDropDown() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const psh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const [ph, ...prds] = sh.getRange(1, 1, 10, 6).getValues().filter(r => r[0]);
  const [ch, ...chcs] = sh.getRange(11, 1, 10, 10).getValues().filter(r => r.join());
  let pidx = {};
  ph.forEach((h, i) => { pidx[h] = i });
  let prd = { pA: [] };
  prds.forEach(r => {
    if (!prd.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
      prd[r[0]] = { type: r[pidx['Type']], size: r[pidx['Size']], color: r[pidx['Color']], material: r[pidx['Material']], length: r[pidx['Length']] };
      prd.pA.push(r[0]);
    }
  });
  let cidx = {};
  let chc = {};
  ch.forEach((h, i) => { cidx[h] = i; chc[h] = [] });
  chcs.forEach(r => {
    r.forEach((c, i) => {
      if (c && c.length > 0) chc[ch[i]].push(c)
    })
  })
  const ps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  ps.setProperty('product_matrix', JSON.stringify(prd));
  ps.setProperty('product_choices', JSON.stringify(chc));
  Logger.log(ps.getProperty('product_matrix'));
  Logger.log(ps.getProperty('product_choices'));
  psh.getRange('A2').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(prd.pA).build());
}

//I chose to use an installable dropdown.  I'm not sure if it's needed.  Its up to you.

function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry')
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast('flag1');
    sh.getRange('C2:G2').clearDataValidations();
    let ps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    let prodObj = JSON.parse(ps.getProperty('product_matrix'));//recovering objects from PropertiesService
    let choiObj = JSON.parse(ps.getProperty('product_choices'));
    let hA = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat();
    let col = {};
    hA.forEach((h, i) => { col[h.toLowerCase()] = i + 1 });
    ["type", "size", "color", "material", "length"].forEach(c => {
      if (choiObj[prodObj[e.value][c]]) {
        sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, col[c]).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(choiObj[prodObj[e.value][c]]).build()).offset(-1,0).setFontColor('#000000');
        sh.showColumns(col[c])
      } else {
        sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, col[c]).offset(-1,0).setFontColor('#ffffff');
        sh.hideColumns(col[c]);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

[image]

demo sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18guAXXjWIMDQilX8Z0Y4_Avogjs2ESMbrZY7Sb9TaxE/edit#gid=0

Sample Data

| P1 | Type | Size | Color | Material | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kurta Pyjamas | No | Sizeethnic_1 | Colorethnic_1 | Materialethnic_3 | Lengthethnic_1 |
| Dhotis | Typethnic_1 | No | Colorethnic_2 | Materialethnic_2 | No |
| Sherwani | No | No | Colorethnic_2 | No | Lengthethnic_2 |
| Men Pyjamas | Typeethnic_2 | No | Colorethnic_2 | No | No |
| Kurtas | No | Sizeethnic_2 | Colorethnic_1 | No | Lengthethnic_1 |
| Ethnic Jackets | No | No | Colorethnic_1 | No | No |

| Typethnic_1 | Typeethnic_2 | Sizeethnic_1 | Sizeethnic_2 | Colorethnic_1 | Colorethnic_2 | Materialethnic_3 | Materialethnic_2 | Lengthethnic_1 | Lengthethnic_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mundu | Churidar | XS | XS | Beige | Green | Blended | Silk Blend | Above Knee | Short |
| Regular Dhoti | Regular Pyjama | S | S | Black | Grey | Cotton | Velevt | Ankle Length | Medium |
| Patiala | M | M | Blue | Maroon | Dupion | Viscose Rayon |  |  |  |
| Jodhpuri | L | L | Brown | Multi |  | Wool |  |  |  |
| Harem | XL | XL | Copper | Mustard |  |  |  |  |  |
| XXL | XXL | Cream |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3XL | 3XL | Gold |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Are your sample data fixed? Or does it change over time in size?

Comment: Yes, it changes over time in size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion

This may not be the cleanest code but you may try this implementation below. Instead of removing columns, it will clear the `Sheet1` headers and their corresponding drop-downs on every new selection on the `A2` drop-down.

> **NOTE:** Since your **sample data** will increase in size overtime, this setup will need you to put the data into a separate sheet tab for a cleaner setup, such as this sample below:

### **`Data1`** sheet tab:

> [image]

### **`Data2`** sheet tab:

> [image]

### ***UPDATED***
***Sample Script***

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var selection = sh.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A2").getValue();  //Get the selection on the dropdowm on cell A2
var data1 = sh.getSheetByName("Data1").getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
var data2 = sh.getSheetByName("Data2").getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

function addHeaders(sheet, values) { //Adds the headers from Column C and beyond
  var startCol = 3; //Column C
  var endCol = startCol +  values.length;
  values.forEach(x => {
    if(startCol <= endCol){
      if(checkHeaderIfYesOrNo(x) == true)return;
      sheet.getRange(1,startCol).setValue(x);
      startCol += 1;
    }
  });
 }

function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() != "A2")return;//Make sure to run onEdit function ONLY when cell A2 is edited/selected
  var headers = [];
  var headerValues = [];
  var temp = [];
  var counter = 0;
  clean();
  data1 = fixDuplicates();
  //find selection name on data1
  for(var x = 0; x< data1.length; x++){
    var name = data1[x][0];
    if(name == selection){
      ///get the headers & their values
      data1[x].forEach(res => {
        if(res != "" & res != selection){
          var index1 = data1[x].indexOf(res); 
          var index2 = data2[0].indexOf(res);
          headers.push([data1[0][index1]]);
          for(var y=0; y< data2.length; y++){
            if(data2[y][index2] != "" && data2[y][index2] != res){
              temp.push("**"+res+"**"+data2[y][index2]); //place raw header data to a temporary variable
            }
          }
          //Set the drop-down data of each headers
          temp.forEach(raw => { //clean the temp array
            if(raw.includes(res)){
              var regex = /\*\*([^*]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*)\*\*/g;
              headerValues.push(raw.replace(regex, ""))
            }
          });
          //Logger.log("Data of the \""+res+"\" header:\n"+headerValues);
          //set data validation per header
          counter += 1;
          if(res.toLowerCase().includes("no"))return; //skip creating data validation for "No" header
          if(res.toLowerCase().includes("yes")) return; //skip creating data validation for "Yes" header 
          sh.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(2,2+counter).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(headerValues).build());
          headerValues = [];
        }
      });
    }
  }
  addHeaders(sh.getSheetByName("Sheet1"), headers);
}

function clean(){ //Clean Sheet 1 on every edit
  sh.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange('C2:Z').clearDataValidations();
  sh.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange('C1:Z').clearContent();
}

function fixDuplicates(){
  var temp = [];
  var data1New = [];
  var count = 1;
  for(var x=0; x<data1.length; x++){
    data1[x].forEach(findIt => {
      if(findIt.toLowerCase().includes("yes") || findIt.toLowerCase().includes("no")){
        temp.push(findIt+count);
        count += 1;
      }else{
        temp.push(findIt);
      }
    })
    data1New.push(temp);
    temp=[];
  }
  return data1New;
}

function checkHeaderIfYesOrNo(h){
  for(var x=0; x<data1.length; x++){
    if(data1[x][0] == selection){
      if(data1[x][data1[0].indexOf(h.toString())].toLowerCase().includes("yes")){
        Logger.log(h +" contains Yes");
        return null;
      }else if(data1[x][data1[0].indexOf(h.toString())].toLowerCase().includes("no")){
        Logger.log(h+" header will not be added as it has \"No\" value");
        return true;
      }else{
        Logger.log("Skip the "+h +" header");
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Demonstration:

[image]

### Sample Execution Log result for review:

[image]

Comment: Getting this error  TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
addHeaders @ Code.gs:8

Comment: I see, please make sure that you're running the `onEdit` function instead of the `addHeaders` on your Apps Script editor as [seen here](https://imgur.com/a/sA8cc5Q). Once you've saved the script on your editor, you can also test it by actually selecting a product on `Sheet1` drop-down

Comment: i have done that but on every edit when i am selecting the option from the drop down it is clearing the data

Comment: Got it. Working it now actually for a fix. My apologies...

Comment: it should only clear the data when there is an edit in A2 in options

Comment: @SameerFarooqui I have updated my script's `onEdit` function to make sure it will only run when cell `A2` is edited/selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241228/discussion-between-irvin-jay-g-and-sameer-farooqui).

Comment: @SameerFarooqui Updated my script. I've added some functions to fix duplicates & check if an extra header contains `yes` / `no` value